# Variable to call directory and files

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script to do a certain actions on my files. Maybe I have a problem with the variable $dir because I don't know what is the right character when I use it on the script.

```
for dir in *; do 
      cd $dir; flapwater -lp ../../ligands/"$dir.mol2" ../A2a1071_PEP_REC.pdb "A2a1071_$dirDock_Complex.pdb"; 
      flapwater -w-auto -i "A2a1071_"$dirDock_Complex.pdb" -o "WF_$dir.pdb" -gl ../../ligands/"$dir.mol2" -gr 6 > WF.log; 
      cd .. ; 
done
```

Example:

If the variable is $dir = 4a the script should be:

```
for dir in *; do 
     cd $dir; flapwater -lp ../../ligands/4a.mol2 ../A2a1071_PEP_REC.pdb A2a1071_4aDock_Complex.pdb; 
     flapwater -w-auto -i A2a1071_4aDock_Complex.pdb -o WF_4a.pdb -gl ../../ligands/4a.mol2 -gr 6 > WF.log; 
     cd .. ; 
done
```

Could someone explain me the write use of $dir please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash can't tell whether `$dirDock_Complex` is a variable name or just a part of it (so it always uses the longest possible name). Use curlies to separate the variable name.

Also, double quote the variable so `cd` works even if the directory name contains whitespace.

```bsh
for dir in * ; do
    cd -- "$dir" || continue # Double quotes.
    flapwater -lp ../../ligands/"$dir.mol2" ../A2a1071_PEP_REC.pdb "A2a1071_${dir}Dock_Complex.pdb"  # Curlies.
    flapwater -w-auto -i "A2a1071_${dir}Dock_Complex.pdb" -o "WF_$dir.pdb" -gl "../../ligands/$dir.mol2" -gr 6 > WF.log # curlies
    cd .. || break
done
```